# Cast geography Polygon to MultiPolygon; function st_multi(geography) does not exist

Tags: postgis, typecast

I'm trying to cast a geography Polygon to a MultiPolygon resulting from a 'geographic' intersection with a circle on Earth of a 10'000m radius, but PostGIS is raising this error when using `ST_Multi` on that resulting Polygon:

```sql
ERROR:  function st_multi(geography) does not exist
LINE 2:  ST_Multi(
         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 15
```

The message is not 100% clear to me, because `ST_Multi` does exist as I successfully used it on many other queries on that same database.

So, I have the feeling that it is simply not able to work on a 'geography' polygon (or maybe the error lies somewhere else?).

Here's a minimal reproducible code snippet (postgis 3.1 / postgres 13.1):

```
SELECT CAST(
  ST_Multi(
    ST_Intersection(
      ST_Simplify(
        ST_MakePolygon(
          ST_Force2D(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
              '{"type":"LineString",
              "coordinates":[
                  [8,48,45],
                  [8.1,47.2,45],
                  [8.2,47.3,45],
                  [8,48,45]
                ],
              "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}'
            )
          )
        ),
        0.001
      ),
      ST_buffer(
        ST_SetSRID(
          CAST(ST_MakePoint(8.1, 47.2) AS GEOGRAPHY), '4326'),
        10000
      )
    )
  ) AS GEOMETRY
);
```

How would you cast a Polygon to a MultiPolygon in that particular case?

Comment: This is even more minimal and works with geography: `SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_Multi(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)',4326),0.1))::geography);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that apparently, [`ST_Multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html) does not appreciate to work on a geography feature.

Therefore, I actually have to use `ST_Multi` ***after*** casting the geography to a proper **geometry** feature (i.e. outside the cast function, and not inside).

This is working:

```sql
SELECT ST_Multi(
  CAST(
    ST_Intersection(
      ST_Simplify(
        ST_MakePolygon(
          ST_Force2D(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
              '{"type":"LineString",
              "coordinates":[
                  [8,48,45],
                  [8.1,47.2,45],
                  [8.2,47.3,45],
                  [8,48,45]
                ],
              "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}'
            )
          )
        ),
        0.001
      ),
      ST_buffer(
        ST_SetSRID(
          CAST(ST_MakePoint(8.1, 47.2) AS GEOGRAPHY), '4326'),
        10000
      )
    ) AS GEOMETRY
  )
);
```

And if I encapsulate all this into [`ST_GeometryType`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) it successfully tells:

| st_geometrytype (text) |
| --- |
| `"ST_MultiPolygon"` |